# ввод с клавиатуры для кросс валидации

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста для кросс валидации сделать ввод с клавиатуры

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
data = pd.read_csv(r'D:\download\ENB2012.csv', ';')
data.head()
kfold = 5 #количество подвыборок для валидации
itog_val = {} #список для записи результатов кросс валидации разных алгоритмов
X = data.drop('Y1', axis=1).values[:, :7] # [y] столбец не должен попадать в [X]
y = data['Y1'].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
print ('обучающая выборка:\n', X_train[:9])
print ('\n')
print ('тестовая выборка:\n', X_test[:7])
clf = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=70)    
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold)
itog_val['AdaBoostClassifier'] = scores.mean()
print ('итог', itog_val)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf.score(X_test, y_test)
y_test_predicted = clf.predict(X_test)
print ('AdaBoostClassifier first 9 predicted values:\n', y_test_predicted[:9])
res = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((y_test, y_test_predicted, X_test)),
                   columns=['Y1','YP'] + data.columns[1:8].tolist())
res
```

Comment: `text = input("Input a = ")` ?

Comment: уточните пожалуйста вопрос - что надо ввести с клавиатуры?

Comment: для кросс валидации kfold = 5 , чтобы после введения с помощью input далее были изменения, то есть чтоб тестовая и обучающая выборка делились от кросс валидации введенной с помощью  input